# How to find unused API from the log file using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, logging, scripting, sh

The goal is to find out the APIs that have not been used in the past seven days. There is a file that stores all API lists, and a file folder that contains daily log data.

**api.txt**(Store all api lists):

```
/api/user/status
/api/property/status
/api/video/banner/list
/api/user/info
/api/user/giftList
/api/user/ticket
...
```

**log data**(store seven days):
[image]

each of log file will look like this

```
2023-01-16 01:20:28.646 +00:00: ID: 1865555 IP:1.2.3.4 POST: /api/user/status Response:1
2023-01-16 01:20:28.646 +00:00: ID: 1444444 IP:1.2.3.4 POST: /api/user/info Response:1
2023-01-16 01:20:28.646 +00:00: ID: 1865555 IP:1.2.3.4 POST: /api/property/status Response:1
2023-01-16 01:20:28.646 +00:00: ID: 1333333 IP:1.2.3.4 GET: /api/video/comments Response:2
2023-01-16 01:20:28.646 +00:00: ID: 1865555 IP:1.2.3.4 GET: /api/user/rate Response:1
...
```

**Methods:**

Start from the first line of the api data (/api/user/status), take the files in the log folder and compare them one by one (seven files). if find that the API is used in the middle, change to the next API(/api/property/status) to check, if the API seven files have not been used, just echo the API.

**What I try:**

Problem1: `if [[ ! $line == *$i* ]];` doesn't work, it works act as `if [[ $line == *$i* ]];` but I want to get the not equal result

Problem2: This is only compare two file, but how can I check the rest of six files inside the loop?

```
file1="api.txt"

file2="2023-01-10_00-00-00.log" 

if [ ! -f "$file1" ] || [ ! -f "$file2" ]; then
    echo "Error: One of the files does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

declare -a lines1

while IFS= read -r line; do
    lines1+=("$line")
done < "$file1"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    for i in "${lines1[@]}"; do 
        if [[ ! $line == *$i* ]];
        then
            echo "$i"
            break
        fi
    done
done < "$file2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep(awk,sed) can work with multiple files. I'd suggest to loop through APIs and grep them in logs for 7 days. Something like this:

```
api_names=( $(cat api.txt) )
log_files=( $(find path_to_logs -type f -daystart -mtime +7) )

for api in "${api_names[@]}"; { grep -q " $api " "${log_files[@]}" || echo $api not used; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first create from the logs a list of all APIs which are actually **used**, i.e. something like

```
grep -hoE ' (GET|POST): /api/[^ ]+' $logdir/*.log | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort -u >used_api.txt
```

Then I would search in api.txt for all lines which are **absent** from the freshly generated `used_api.txt`

```
grep -vxF -f used_api.txt api.txt >unused_api.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat *.log | awk 'NR==FNR{u[$8];next} !($0 in u)' - api.txt
```

- stream the logs into awk as first input file (`-`)
- set an array index to value of field 8

  - (optionally, perform other tests before storing)
- after logs read, loop over lines in api.txt

  - if value is not an array index, print it

---

If logs could contain many values of field 8 that are not of interest, you could reorder, and only store relevant values. For example:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { api[$0]; next }
    $8 in api { used[$8] }
    END { for (a in api) if (!(a in used)) print a }
' api.txt *.log
```

Or you could initialise the api set and delete from it:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { unused[$0]; next }
    { delete unused[$8] }
    END { for (api in unused) print api }
' api.txt *.log
```